# Reactjs this.props not rendering inside link element

Tags: reactjs

So I have a react component:

```
var ReportRow = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <tr>
          <td><a href="/report/{this.props.report.pk}/">{this.props.report.pk}</a></td>
          <td><a href="/report/{this.props.report.pk}/">{this.props.report.name}</a></td>
          <td><a href="/report/{this.props.report.pk}/">{this.props.report.unit}</a></td>
          <td><a href="/report/{this.props.report.pk}/">{this.props.report.date}</a></td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
});
```

And everything is rendering great except for some reason the report.pk isn't being filled in the href link. It works for the display, but not for the report link.

Instead my link looks like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/report/%7Bthis.props.report.pk%7D/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like this ?

```
<a href={"/report/" + this.props.report.pk + "/"}>
```

Or you can use templates like so:

```
<a href={`/report/${this.props.report.pk}/`}>
```

Another workaround with [***fiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/35011/)

```
render: function() {
  var string = "hello " + this.props.name + "com";
  return <a href={string}>Hello</a>;
}
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: great idea. But I get a syntax error. Reactjs doesn't like it.

Comment: Had the same problem with `this.state`, this solved it. I think the poster and me misunderstood how the variable interpolation worked, thinking it was more like other template libs that replaces variables inside quotes too.

Answer (score 0):

try console.log(this.props.report) or console.log(this.props.report.pk) to check whether your props does have value assigned or not.

Comment: I know that it has a value. Because I am rendering the pk not in the link as well and it shows up fine.